# My iphone 6 plus is bent and not powering on, need to retrieve data not backup to cloud

Tags: icloud, photos, iphone

First, thanks in advance for any help. I got the new iPhone 6 plus four months ago from AT&T. The phone has been working great the whole time until i sat on it when getting into my car last Friday evening and my phone bent and went dead. I made appointment in the Apple store to set up repair service and they told me they could not retrieve any photos or data that was not backed up to the cloud. I took a family trip to Hawaii to see my son in the military the day after the last back up due to the cloud being full. I cannot lose these photos. I am willing to send in the hard drive somewhere to retrieve this data but cant find where to do this or get the phone repaired enough to power on to retrieve the data. Any thoughts on how to best get this accomplished?

Comment: Give these people a call and see what they say: http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com/devices-supported/apple-iphone-data-recovery/

Answer (score 1):

There are companies out there, although I can't recommend any that claim to be able to recover data off broken iPhones, I've not tried them, the iPhone doesn't have a hard drive, the whole device is on a single computer circuit board, it's going to destroy the phone trying to get it repaired.

Data recovery is expensive, and once your phone has been modified by a third party the price for getting Apple to repair/replace your phone will escalate as they won't do an out of warranty service on a phone that has been modified by a 3rd party unauthorised centre.

In other words you'll have to buy a new phone, and fork out a load of money on data recovery.